# Copy of mysql_store_result(conn); into buffer or array

Tags: mysql, c, sockets

I have one client c program, one Server c program. Client and Server program are communicating via socket. Server Program is connected with mysql.

The Client send an sql query to server via socket e.g. Select * from exampleTable;
The Server will receive this query and forward it to Sql server for execution.

Now my problem is
when i got the result res = mysql_store_result(conn); i want to send it back to client via socket.

Anybody who have any idea how can i do this because i am unable to store the result in buffer or array so that i can send the buffer or array via socket to client program.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what kind of protocol you want to implement for your socket connection.  You need to decide if you want binary or text, and the format you wish to send the data in.  When you call mysql_store_result, the data is already stored in memory, but not in a packed data structure or anything like that.  You will need to iterate over the result(s), possibly get the field names and types if they are not known, and iterate over all of the rows and columns to fill your buffer with the data in the format you want.

Once you have done that, and can provide us with a more specific problem (and hopefully some code), we will probably be able to help you with that.

Comment: thanks for your time:
For socket i use tcp protocol 
here is my code 

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < number_Of_Feilds ; i++)
  {
   printf("%s  ", row [i] ? row [i] : "NULL");
  }
  printf("\n");
 }

i can retrieve the information at server program. now i want to send result to client program via socket in string format .. How can i copy the query result to buffer or array so that i can send my buffer or array to client program

Comment: or is there is any other way to pass mysql_store_result() directly to client via socket

Comment: rather than printing it to stdout with printf(), print it to a buffer using snprintf(), and then use send() to transmit it over your socket.  edit: If you are using some sort of Microsoft sockets, I don't know what the function is to send over a socket.  The linux function used for this is send(), though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.. i also try snprintf but i does not copy the whole table..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10952215/bob-shaffer i also put the code here

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:

```
res = mysql_store_result(conn);
   number_of_fields = mysql_num_fields(res);

   while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
   {
       for (i =0; i< number_of_fields ; i++)
       {
        // printf("%s  ", row [i] ? row [i] : "NULL");
        snprintf(buff,MAX, "%s ", row [i] ? row [i] : "NULL");
        }
   }
   write(client_socket, buff, sizeof(buff));
   close(client_socket);
```